# How do I know which file a program is trying to access?

Tags: files, process

I have a program which I am trying to run, however when I run it; it just complains that it can't find a particular file.

However I have no idea which folder it is trying to find this particular file in. I have a copy of the required file, I just need to know which folder to copy it too.

Is there any way to show in real time which files are being accessed or which files are trying and failing to be accessed?

I am using Ext4 filesystem if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details about the problem. What was the particular program you were trying to run and how you tried it?

Comment: It's an in-house program. I've had this problem with various other programs too in the past so I'm looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(I first posted my answer at this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192274/is-there-tool-to-see-call-stack-of-running-thread-similar-to-process-explorer-by), but removed it from there and posted it here, as it is more relevant.)

There are several ways you can investigate what files and libraries processes have opened; the main tools are `lsof`, `strace` and `ltrace`. Sometimes it is necesary to run them with `sudo`, so the program has access to everything it needs to gain an accurate snapshot of what a program is calling.

1) With `lsof` you need to find the process id you want to query, so use, for example:

```
lsof -c firefox
```

which will list all the files `firefox` has open and all its calls to system shared libraries. (Firefox currently has a pid of 3310 on my system, so you could also use `lsof -p 3310`, but you would have had to look up the process id first with `ps aux | grep [f]irefox`
 ). More information on `lsof` is detailed in this useful [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html).

2) `ltrace` and `strace` have very similar functions and options, and are very useful for finding out detailed information about what calls a process is making. The main difference is that `ltrace` usually only traces `library` calls (although it can trace system calls with the `-S` option), while `strace` traces both `library` and other `system` calls. More information on tracing processes is available in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-apptracing/index.html). `Lsof` is probably more useful for you if you want to examine an already running process but `strace` can also do this and monitor the calls in real time when given a process pid (sudo is always used when one attaches to a process):

```
sudo strace -p 3310
```

**but** it is much more useful to launch the program with `strace` and see what was called, as in the following example:

```
strace -f -e trace=open /usr/bin/firefox
```

You can just run `strace` with the target process and no options, but the switches here mean that child processes are traced (`-f`) and that all open system calls are traced (`-e trace=open`) 
If you want to save the output to file you can specify `-o ~/firefox.trace` before specifying `/usr/bin/firefox`.

If you want a summary list of library calls, for example, you could use

```
ltrace -c /usr/bin/leafpad
```

and then exit the program and the list would be produced. Omit the `-c` option to view the calls in real time.

The results from `strace` and `ltrace` may not be greatly useful to you, as they are difficult to decipher unless you know what you are looking for, but `lsof` should provide some basic useful information.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do this seems to be to run the program through `strace` and watch for stat64() calls (which get file info) or open() calls which open files.

So you do:

```
strace -e stat64 -e open [program name]
```

And in the resulting output look for:

(No such file or directory)

The path it was trying to open should be to the left of this error.