# Is there tool to see call-stack of running thread similar to Process Explorer by Sysinternals?

Tags: software-recommendation, debugging, system-monitor

Is there tool to see call-stack of running thread similar to Process Explorer by Sysinternals ?

So far I tried htop, qps and Linux Process Explorer. None of them can provide that information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdb`, the GNU debugging utility, can provide such functionality, although **only** for selected programs or processes individually. There is **not** an easy way to do it and switch between the call-stacks of the processes running on the system like the Sysinternals program does on Windows. However, you could try `pstack`, but I have not had much success with it.

You also have to install the `dbg` packages (i.e. the symbol packages) so that any `gdb` call-stack backtrace will work. See [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Debug_Symbol_Packages) for more information on these packages. Basically, the `dbg` version of the package is installed very like the normal one is. You run, for example,

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core-dbg
```

You can do a backtrace on a program by starting the program under `gdb` or you can do one on a program already running by attaching `gdb` to that process: please see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Backtrace) for further details.

Please see [the official manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Stack.html#Stack) for more information on `gdb` and backtracing and  more generally useful information is here at the [Ubuntu debugging page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures).

Additional ways of analysing running processes using `strace`,etc, which are of use to developers, etc, in analysing a process and its system calls, as opposed to stack calls, have been moved to this question here (as I thought they are now more relevant there):

- [How do I know which file a program is trying to access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191964/how-do-i-know-which-file-a-program-is-trying-to-access)

Comment: Thanks a lot for very detailed answer. I'll try everything tonight. But there is no way to get call-stack of running thread I assume ?

Comment: @ruslan I've edited my answer and moved the strace and ltrace discussion to the linked askubuntu question, as I realised that you are more interested in looking at call stacks using something like gdb. See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/191964/how-do-i-know-which-file-a-program-is-trying-to-access/192634#192634. I hope this is ok, as I realised it wasn't really what you wanted here.